# What's wrong with this regex expression?

Tags: php, regex

i want to preg_match the following code:

```
{{{/foo:bar/a/0/b}}}
```

This is my regex (which doesn't work, and i don't understand why):

```
|{{{\/([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]\_]*\:[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]\_]*)(?:\/([[:alnum:]\_]*))+}}}|Uism
```

Expected result:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => {{{/foo:bar/a/0/b}}}
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => foo:bar
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
    )
)
```

The result i get:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => {{{/foo:bar/a/0/b}}}
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => foo:bar
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
    )
)
```

I only get the last element back. So what's wrong with it?

Comment: The modifiers `i`, `s` and `m` are useless here.

Answer (score 1):

You're repeating the second capturing group:

```
(?:
 \/
 (
  [[:alnum:]\_]*
 )
)+
```

On each repetition of the outer non-capturing group, the contents of the inner capturing group are overwritten, which is the reason why only the last match is preserved. This is standard behavior across all regex engines.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=(^.*$)|(?:\/(.*?)(?:\/|})))
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/3

Answer (score 0):

Each subsequent match of the same capture group will overwrite the previous one; that's why you end up with just `b`.

What I would suggest in this case is to match the whole block first and then use a simpler `explode()` to dig out the inner data; use this expression:

```
|{{{\/([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]\_]*\:[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]\_]*(?:\/[[:alnum:]\_]*)+)}}}|U
```

Then, with the resulting `$matches` array (third argument to `preg_match()`):

```
$data = explode('/', $matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is complete overkill for something that should be quite simple:

```
$rex = "@[{]{3}/(\w+:\w+)/(\w)/(\d)/(\w)[}]{3}@";
$str = "{{{/foo:bar/a/0/b}}}";

preg_match($rex, $str, $res);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {{{/foo:bar/a/0/b}}}
    [1] => foo:bar
    [2] => a
    [3] => 0
    [4] => b
)
```